# How to retrieve data using select box with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have more than 100 rows in an database and they are from different subjects, like Database lessons or Network lessons. I want that the user can choose what questions from those subjects he want to display. So I was thinking in using one select box, but I don't know how to handle the selected box with the database query. How could I do that ?

My code currently :

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class =  "container">

        <?php
            $query = "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo BETWEEN 1 AND 100";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
             while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
                echo  "<li>" . $fetch[0] . "</li>";
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that he just shows all the lessons from different subjects here, but I want to give the user the choice to choose what questions he want to display.

Example :

If the user want to display only Database lessons he would choose through the select box and would appear at the screen all questions from this particular subject, not all the subjects questions.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML `<select>` element takes a list of `<option>` elements:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

That snippet will produce a drop-down list to pick from the options Option 1 and Option 2 whose values are 1 and 2 respectively: https://jsfiddle.net/ux245gz3/

For your case, every `<li>` element you're creating should be an `<option>` inside of a `<select>` block:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <select id="subject_selection">
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo BETWEEN 1 AND 100";

                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
                    echo  "<option value=\"$fetch[0]\">" . $fetch[0] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will produce a list of each of the names of the subjects with the value of the selection set to the displayed name. The [MDN article on `<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) will have more information about this.

**Update to answer the full question:**

You'll want to update the query to select a display value and the ID for each subject (assuming the primary key of the `'conteudo'` table is called `'id'`:

`SELECT id, def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo BETWEEN 1 AND 100;`

Then you can use the id as the value for each option:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT id, def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo BETWEEN 1 AND 100";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<option value=\"$fetch[0]\">$fetch[1]</option>";
    }
?>
```

Then, once the user selects an option from the dropdown you can perform a `GET` to the page and query against the questions or lessons that have the proper relationship to the selected subject via the subject's id submitted by the form.

`SELECT * FROM <licao/pergunta> WHERE contuedo_id = $_GET["id"];`

As a friendly aside, at this point you should look into using something like [PHP's PDO library](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to automatically handle sanitizing your dynamically generated SQL statements.

Comment: I _think_ he needs checkboxes (although he said `select boxes`). Nonetheless; the principe stays the same, and a good answer, so +1

Comment: Your answer is really good, but what I wanted was to select the subject, like Database or Network and appear the questions from those subjects. This one makes appear all the questions from all subjects in the select box. How could I make when selecting the subject appear the questions from this particular subject ? I will edit my questions to show sort of less what I want.

Comment: I want like, after selecting one of those options, they would display with an list the questions from this subject that was selected in the select box.

Comment: Hopefully the edit is helpful! I'm assuming you don't have a front-end framework you're trying to work with and that you'll go back to the database to retrieve the the lessons or questions that have the subject the user selected.